# iOS Push Notification not sent from server (Jetpack)

Tags: ios, wordpress, push-notification, jetpack, simperium

I'm implementing an iOS application to manage my self-hosted website. My app make use of the many features already built for **WordPress-iOS** app, but it has differences and extra features.

One of the problem I'm currently having is that push notification was not sent from Jetpack (WordPress.com server) to Apple's APNs, because I'm not getting any notification on my device. I have already registered successfully my device token with Jetpack during app launch.

My problem *could be* the certificate key (.pem) file not getting uploaded to Wordpress.com (which I do not have access). Is this the reason why I'm not receiving any push notification to my iphone?

Additionally, I'm not getting any result on the `NotificationsViewController`. I do not have Simperium account setup yet. Could that be my problem for getting no results in NotificationsViewController?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about the delay!. For the time being, i'm afraid that WordPress iOS doesn't support 3rd party apps integrations with its Notifications stack.

Meaning that if you'd like to handle `Push Notifications` support, you'd need to implement a `WordPress.org` plugin to handle the APN message delivery.

As per the `Simperium` side, there is no 3rd party app support -at least for now!- due to security restrictions.

If there's anything we could help you with, [you may find us on the WordPress Slack](https://make.wordpress.org/chat/) (#mobile channel!).

Best,
Jorge